# gRPC and ASP.NET Core: serverside reflection

Tags: asp.net-core, reflection, grpc

I've been trying to implement the concepts of serverside reflection described in https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/server-reflection.md and for C#  https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/csharp/server_reflection.md in the implementation of ASP.NET Core. You have to somehow configure Kestrel to enable Reflection first. I just don't succeed and have to give up. This is the tricky part that somehow has to be implemented in ASP.NET Core.

// the reflection service will be aware of "Greeter" and "ServerReflection" services.
var reflectionServiceImpl = new ReflectionServiceImpl(Greeter.Descriptor, ServerReflection.Descriptor);

```
server = new Server()
{
    Services =
    {
        // the server will serve 2 services, the Greeter and the ServerReflection
        ServerReflection.BindService(new GreeterImpl()),
        ServerReflection.BindService(reflectionServiceImpl)
    },
    Ports = { { "localhost", 50051, ServerCredentials.Insecure } }
};
server.Start();
```

Does somebody know how to enable serverside reflection in ASP.NET Core with Kestrel? Or even better has a complete working example of serverside reflection in C# ASP.NET Core?

**Update**

It seems that the default implementation of .NET Core 3.1 doesn't support the reflection yet. The NuGet https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/ does work and seamlessly integrates in ASP.NET Core. The example covers discovering services on a server. I can't find concrete descriptions how to iterate through all methods on a service and all fields in a message. Maybe JamesNK can help?

Comment: Did you tried anyrhing yet? If so, please show it.

Comment: Nothing that compiled ;( due to lack of knowing all ins-and-outs of Kestrel.

Comment: hmmm... it should be independent of kestrel